# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) while Achieving?

Tags: ios, swift, archive

I know many developers asked the same question but no solution worked for me.
I am trying to Archive my project but I am getting error:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is my Screenshots :-

[image].

[image]

I tried :

1. clean and build.
2. Enable bit code.
3. Remove 'Derived Data'.

Is there anything that I have to add?

Comment: can you show the full error

Comment: Do you have GoogleMaps pod?

Comment: Check build log. There is more detailed description of the error

Comment: No @V.Khambir I have GoogleSignIn Pod

Comment: I don't know why someone gives down vote .If I have some issue and I think I can't ask here.Thanks

Comment: drop us the error

Comment: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) ?
I am clicking on error but is't showing this only.

Build and run is working fine but While Archive it's giving the error.

Comment: I just Edited my Question.
Please check it.

Comment: Pro-tip: chatty material such as "please help me", "help is appreciated", thanks", "thanks in advance" (etc) tends to be trimmed out here, since it does not add anything to the post. We thank people here by upvoting and accepting. Keep it short and sweet!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. It was because of GoogleMaps pod.

1. Remove any Google pods from `pod` file
2. call `pod install`
3. Return back Google pods into `pod` file
4. call `pod install` again

Comment: But I have GoogleSignIn Pod only.

Comment: @kishor0011, try to do it with this pod.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue, today I tried this and resolved me issue. I am using XCode ver 8.3.2.

command+option+shift+K  -> Clean

Try, Might help you.

You can also try this 
First close the XCode, Run the commands in terminal. then restart the XCode.

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Comment: I was getting this error since last 1 month while I was trying to run the application on simulator, Today I installed XCode 9, it worked for me on XCode 9.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know but I changed one small thing "Enable Bitcode" in Build Settings and its working fine.

Thanks to all for sharing your knowledge.